# How to like posts with facebook sdk

Tags: android

It's my code,I got error

```
Button likeView = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.like_view);
    likeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Request reqlike = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "322372034467971_1025413444163823" + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    // PARSE THE "response"`enter code here` TO CHECK FOR ERRORS OR SHOW A SUCCESS MESSAGE OR SOMETHING
                }
            });
            Request.executeBatchAndWait(reqlike);
        }
    });
```

> {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus:
>   -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: com.facebook.FacebookException: Session provided to a Request in
>   un-opened state.}, isFromCache:false}

Comment: which facebook sdk version you are using??

Comment: I use version 3.21.0

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but try it

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```